# How can I tell which weapons are one or two handed?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've accumulated several stickers, strap-ons, and pieces of armor that provide buffs to the damage of my one and two handed weapons, as well as to bows and thrown weapons. It's easy to tell the latter two groups apart, but I can't tell how I'm supposed to know whether a weapon is one or two handed. When I preview them on the equip screen, they all look like they're being held in 'one hand' at the characters side, so I have no idea, other than my own intuition based on the physical size of the model in question which... doesn't seem like a good way to figure this out.

I'm sure there's an easier way to identify the difference that I'm just not spotting, so what is it?

Answer (score 11):

One easy way to tell, I've found, is by how your character holds the weapon when equipped. In the inventory screen, if the new kid extends his arm, resting the bottom of the weapon on the ground, it is two handed. If his arm is down and the weapon is held out at a nearly forty-five degree angle, it is one handed.

If there's any remaining doubt: equip the weapon, exit the menu, face the camera and look at how you are holding it. Two handed weapons will be held in both hands, while one handed weapons will only be held in a single hand, looking much like you do in the inventory screen.

[image: Difference between 1-handed and 2-handed]